# Set cart item custom prices from session data in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

I Made a custom form option on site to update price and send that data through ajax and try to get in filter woocommerce_before_calculate_totals Session.

Here is code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_total_price', 99 );

function calculate_total_price( $cart_object ) 
{
        global $woocommerce;
        session_start();    
        $tac_dd_discounted_price = $_SESSION['wdm_user_price_data'];
        $target_product_id = $_SESSION['wdm_user_product_id_data'].'<br/>.';
        $_SESSION['productlist'][] =
        [
            'price' => $tac_dd_discounted_price,
            'productid' => $target_product_id
        ];
        $arrys = array_merge( $_SESSION[ "productlist" ]);
        $_SESSION[ "productlist" ] = array_unique($arrys);
        // This unique array created in seesion fro multi product which show correct data.

        $price_blank="1";
         foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
               $id= $cart_item['data']->get_id();
               //$target_product_id=$arrys['productlist']['productid'];
               //$tac_dd_discounted_price=$arrys['productlist']['price'];
            if ( $id == $target_product_id ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price($tac_dd_discounted_price);

                }
            else
            {
             $cart_item['data']->set_price($my_price['productlist']['price']); 
            }   

          }

}
```

But issue is for one product in cart price show correct but when try to add two product the Seession variable append same value in both product

Comment: Edit your and clarify question please, instead of adding code and explanations in answers threads, that are not answers. Also when you do that, nobody knows it as there is no notifications. You need to add a comment on the answer to notify the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

First, instead of using PHP `$_SESSION` you should better use WooCommerce dedicated [`WC_Session`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session.html) class:

```
// Set the data (the value can be also an indexed array)
WC()->session->set( 'custom_key', 'value' );

// Get the data
WC()->session->get( 'custom_key' );
```

Now in your code function, you are just getting from PHP Session **one** product and *one* price in:

```
$tac_dd_discounted_price = $_SESSION['wdm_user_price_data'];
$target_product_id = $_SESSION['wdm_user_product_id_data']; // ==> Removed .'<br/>.'
```

Instead you should need to get an array of product IDs and prices when there is many products in cart.

Also, you don't need `global $woocommerce;`…

> As you don't show all other related JS/Ajax/PHP code and as your question is not detailed, is not possible to help you more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I did it anyone who used custom session for price need to update the cart and checkout page this is the hook which will help you a lot.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item' , 'set_woo_prices');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session',  'set_session_prices', 20 , 3 );

function set_woo_prices( $woo_data ) {
  session_start();    
  $tac_dd_discounted_price = $_SESSION['wdm_user_price_data'];
  $target_product_id = $_SESSION['wdm_user_product_id_data'];
  if ( ! isset($tac_dd_discounted_price ) || empty ($tac_dd_discounted_price ) ) { return $woo_data; }
  $woo_data['data']->set_price( $tac_dd_discounted_price );
  $woo_data['my_price'] = $tac_dd_discounted_price;
  return $woo_data;
}

function  set_session_prices ( $woo_data , $values , $key ) {
    if ( ! isset( $woo_data['my_price'] ) || empty ( $woo_data['my_price'] ) ) { return $woo_data; }
    $woo_data['data']->set_price( $woo_data['my_price'] );
    return $woo_data;
}
```